# Select2 3.5.2 mousedown jumps to top of list in IE10 & IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11, jquery-select2

Using Select2 v3.5.2 to create a dynamic option list. The input allows users to select from the list, type to search through options and if the option doesn't exist it is created. The function which created this data is called within an angular controller. (ui-select was not used for this particular input as I did not see how to implement the search + custom input when this was implemented)

```
var dataQuant = {results: []};
for (var key in response.defaultQuantities) {
    var objQuant = response.defaultQuantities[key];         
    dataQuant.results.push({id:key, text:key + 'otherText'});
}


$('.customClass').select2({
    createSearchChoice:function(term, data) {                 
        if ($(data).filter(function() {return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0; }).length===0) {
            return {id:term, text:term};
        }
    },
    matcher: function(term, text) {
        return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())==0;
    },
    data: dataQuant,
    dropdownCssClass: "customClass2",
    selectOnBlur: true,
    initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        var data = {id: response.defaultQuantity , text: response.defaultQuantity};
        callback(data);
    }
});

$('.customClass').on('change',function(){
    var newQuantityData = $('.customClass').select2('data');
    if ($scope.formData["quantity"] != newQuantityData.id){             
        $scope.formData["quantity"] = newQuantityData.id;
        $scope.updateFunction();  
    }
});
```

This works perfectly fine in chrome/firefox/opera/safari & IE9 and below. In IE10 and 11 any options seen initially can be clicked and work fine. Any options in the option list hidden initially (user has to scroll to) `mousedown` jumps back up to the top of the option list. If the mouse is held down and you then scroll back down the options when released the correct option is selected.

After some searching I have found that within the `select.js` under
`// single
postprocessResults: function (data, initial, noHighlightUpdate) {`
the culprit was

```
if (initial === true && selected >= 0) {
    this.highlight(selected);
} else {
    this.highlight(0);
}
```

All other browsers have the 'initial' value as true passed into the function. IE10/11 has an object passed in which fails at the if statement resulting in the first option being highlighted. I'm not sure why an object is being passed in rather than `true/false` which it seems is what it's expecting. Anyone with more understanding of Select2 able to weigh in?

**EDIT:**

After removing `this.highlight(0)` I have now found that custom inputs that didn't exist before are not selected, so clicking the enter key does not select them. For now I'm just going to add a conditional to ignore this line if in IE.

Comment: Have you checked out the HTML5 <datalist>? This component may help you. 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp

Comment: Check your version number again, Select2 3.5.4 doesn't exist.

Comment: You also appear to be using Select2 with AngularJS (bad move, usually). There is `ui-select` that is a native Angular replacement for Select2.

Comment: Not used <datalist> before - looks useful but the lack of support in Safari & < IE9 would be an issue. Thanks @KevinBrown I did mean 3.5.2. UI-select covered in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using and seems to function correctly in all browsers.

Changing

```
if (initial === true && selected >= 0) {
    this.highlight(selected);
} else {
    this.highlight(0);
}
```

to

```
if (initial === true && selected >= 0) {
    this.highlight(selected);
} else {
    var docMode = document.documentMode,
    hasDocumentMode = (docMode !== undefined), 
    isIE10 = (docMode === 10),
    isIE11 = (docMode === 11);

    if(hasDocumentMode && (isIE11 || isIE10)){                       
        if(initial.target.value == data.results[0].id || data.results.length == 1){
            this.highlight(0);
        }
    }else{
        this.highlight(0);                           
    }
}
```

Option list no longer jumps to the top in IE 10/11, but still allows users to enter custom values and the 'enter' key selects the typed values.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this with the following:

```
var scrollTop;
$('#mySelect2').on("select2:selecting", function( event ){
    var $pr = $( '#'+event.params.args.data._resultId ).parent();
    scrollTop = $pr.prop('scrollTop');
});
$('#mySelect2').on("select2:select", function( event ){
    var $pr = $( '#'+event.params.data._resultId ).parent();
    $pr.prop('scrollTop', scrollTop );
});
```

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but essentially we listen for the selecting event and then grab the current scrollTop of the selectable options panel. On the actual selection, we reset the panel's scrollTop back to its original. This happens so fast that you should see no jump in the control window. Only test with Select2 v. 4.x.

The nice thing about this solution is that you don't have to hack the component or include anything in your config functions.